# How to figure out where JSONDecodeError is occurring

Tags: python, json

I have data that has been scraped for us by another company and one of the columns comes in json that has email address and the type of email professional or personal. Sometimes it is a list of one json object and sometimes is is a list of 2 or 3. I have tried this on other files the same company sent us but this one throws a JSONDecodeError and I don't know how to find the offending row out of the 20k.

Here is the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-f29317e3c5d7> in <module>
      4 # data['Emails'] = data['Emails'].str.extract(r's":\s"(.*?)",')
      5 data['Emails'] = data['Emails'].fillna('~')
----> 6 data['Emails'] = [[item['address'] for item in json.loads(d)] for d in data['Emails']] #Figure out why happening on batch 3
      7 #extract first email the put rest in another column
      8 data['Associated_Emails'] = data['Emails'].apply(lambda x: x[1:])

<ipython-input-217-f29317e3c5d7> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 # data['Emails'] = data['Emails'].str.extract(r's":\s"(.*?)",')
      5 data['Emails'] = data['Emails'].fillna('~')
----> 6 data['Emails'] = [[item['address'] for item in json.loads(d)] for d in data['Emails']] #Figure out why happening on batch 3
      7 #extract first email the put rest in another column
      8 data['Associated_Emails'] = data['Emails'].apply(lambda x: x[1:])

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyfinance/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pyfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Here is my code that is causing the error:

```
data['Emails'] = [[item['address'] for item in json.loads(d)] for d in data['Emails']]
```

as I said it worked on 4 of the 5 files they sent us but this one it won't.

Can anyone help me know how to find the offending row?

The json comes in this format for example:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: catch the exception, and print the offending json line. Or print all lines prior to decoding. Last line before the crash is the faulty one

Comment: Replace the list comprehension with an ordinary loop. Then you can add `print()` calls in the loop to see where it's happening.

Comment: Thank you! @Jean-FrançoisFabre and @Barmar! Don't know why I didn't think of that.